# How to add a note with an oddly shaped Javascript table

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

On my website I have a schedule optimization for semester, classes, times, and locations. After optimization is run, several tables of choices show up.  I want to show an empty semester in the table. here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

I know my table looks ugly, but I can't put blanks in the table to make the columns / side complete because i'm running complex calculations on the data in the table that would get disrupted if I were to put blanks in (it would try to do look-ups on blanks). I can't tell it to ignore the box if it's a blank either (Just go with me here). So, is there a way to add a note in that area that says "No classes for this semester" programmatically? The results are often different sizes so I can't like hardcode in a location  on my website for the note. I need it to just know where to go. I didn't think this was possible but wanted to pose the idea to you guys. Ideas?

This would be the end goal:

--tons of results in form of tables ---

one example result:

[image]

IF it is even possible to close in the table so it's a complete box that would be great. ****I NEED A JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY SOLUTION

UPDATED: Based on the replies so far, I tried this:

```
 if(classes.length === 0){
            var $noClasses = $('<td></td>').html('No Classes available');
            $noClasses.colSpan = "3";
            $table.append($noClasses);          

    }
```

and this gave me

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [`colSpan`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-84645244)?

Comment: I agree with @Oriol. What you're asking is how to span cells across rows/columns. You're still building out a standard HTML table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the code that ended up working:

```
 if(classes.length === 0){
                     var $noClasses = $('<td colspan="3"></td>').addClass('noClass').html("No Classes ");   
}
```

but I had to take out some of the html/css from the javascript because it was getting too confusing to implement this part. I made a template with icanhaz and converted some of the code and then this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowspan` and `colspan` to accommodate the 'awkwardness' of your table structure. The table structure is still standard, you're just wanting to span your cells across rows and/or columns:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            td,th{
                border-style: groove;

            }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Title1</th>
                <th>Title2</th>
                <th>Title3</th>
                <th>Title4</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">Semester1</td>
                <td>Class1</td>
                <td>Time1</td>
                <td>Loc1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Class2</td>
                <td>Time2</td>
                <td>Loc2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Class3</td>
                <td>Time3</td>
                <td>Loc3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Semester2</td>
                <td colspan="3">No Classes available</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Semester3</td>
                <td>Class1</td>
                <td>Time1</td>
                <td>Loc1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: but how do i accommodate for the fact that i cant tell if its always going to be the second row or the third row or the 15th row?

Comment: You will have to figure out what conditions need to be checked. Depending on the evaluation of your condition, you will need to have the code decide when to span across the column/row or not.